# Is Time.zone.now.to_date equivalent to Date.today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is `Time.zone.now.to_date` equivalent to `Date.today`?

Another way to put it: will `Time.zone.now.to_date == Date.today` always be `true`?

If not, what's the best way to get a Date object corresponding to "now" in the application time zone?

Comment: This is a great reference for dates and times to avoid time zone gotchas: http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/

Comment: Correct way is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27397193/115363

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They are not always the same. Time.zone.now.to_date will use the applications time zone, while Date.today will use the servers time zone. So if the two lie on different dates then they will be different. An example from my console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :036 > Time.zone = "Sydney"
 => "Sydney" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :037 > Time.zone.now.to_date
 => Wed, 21 Sep 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :038 > Date.today
 => Tue, 20 Sep 2011
```

Answer (score 14):

Even easier: `Time.zone.today`

I also wrote a little helper method `Date.today_in_zone` that makes it really easy to get a "today" `Date` for a specific time zone without having to *change* `Time.zone`:

```
 # Defaults to using Time.zone
 > Date.today_in_zone
=> Fri, 26 Oct 2012

 # Or specify a zone to use
 > Date.today_in_zone('Sydney')
=> Sat, 27 Oct 2012
```

To use it, just throw this in a file like `'lib/date_extensions.rb'` and `require 'date_extensions'`.

```
class Date
  def self.today_in_zone(zone = ::Time.zone)
    ::Time.find_zone!(zone).today
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to learn the current time through:

```
Time.current
```

This will automatically check to see if you have timezone set then it will call Time.zone.now, but if you've not it will call just Time.now.

*Also, don't forget to set your timezone in application.rb*

Answer (score 2):

```
# system timezone
Time.now.to_date == Date.today

# application timezone
Time.zone.now.to_date == Time.current.to_date == Time.zone.today == Date.current
```

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-current
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-c-current