# Age calculation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to write a rails application but presently the display for the date of birth is shown like the normal date format, but I wouldl love to show in views the age instead

The method I have in controller is below and I have a column DOb in my database for date of birthL

```
def age
  @user = user
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - @user.dob.year - (@user.dob.to_date.change(:year => now.year) > now ? 1 : 0)
end
```

It shows like DOB: 23/5/2011, but I would like it to be age in years instead.

How do I also put a validator that checks if age is below 18 years?

Comment: I don't understand the problem of the display of the age; post relevant code of your view to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the validator, you can use a [custom method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods):

```
validate :over_18

def over_18
  if dob + 18.years >= Date.today
    errors.add(:dob, "can't be under 18")
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it should be just `>` otherwise a birthday of 18 won't count.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this question and thought I'd post a more modern answer that takes advantage of Rails convenience method syntax and custom validators.

## Custom Age Validator

This validator will take an options hash for the field name you'd like to validate and the minimum age requirement.

```
# Include somewhere such as the top of user.rb to make sure it gets loaded by Rails.
class AgeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def initialize(options)
    super
    @field = options[:field] || :birthday
    @min_age = options[:min_age] || 18
    @allow_nil = options[:allow_nil] || false
  end

  def validate(record)
    date = record.send(@field)
    return if date.nil? || @allow_nil

    unless date <= @min_age.years.ago.to_date
      record.errors[@field] << "must be over #{@min_age} years ago."
    end
  end

end
```

## Example Usage

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with AgeValidator, { min_age: 18, field: :dob }
end
```

---

## `User#age` convenience method

And to calculate the user's age for display, you'll want to be careful to calculate around leap years.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def age

    return nil unless dob.present?
    # We use Time.current because each user might be viewing from a
    # different location hours before or after their birthday.
    today = Time.current.to_date

    # If we haven't gotten to their birthday yet this year.
    # We use this method of calculation to catch leapyear issues as
    # Ruby's Date class is aware of valid dates.
    if today.month < dob.month || (today.month == dob.month && dob.day > today.day)
      today.year - dob.year - 1
    else
      today.year - dob.year
    end

  end
end
```

### And the spec!

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe User do
  describe :age do
    let(:user) { subject.new(dob: 30.years.ago) }
    it "has the proper age" do
      expect(user.age).to eql(30)

      user.birthday += 1.day
      expect(user.age).to eql(29)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Time.current.to_date` to `Date.today`, is better

Comment: `Date.today` won't work well if you happen to set the app's timezone to something besides the system time. See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937161/is-time-zone-now-to-date-equivalent-to-date-today

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when calculating age. Here's a correct method:

```
def age(as_at = Time.now)
  as_at = as_at.utc.to_date if as_at.respond_to?(:utc)
  as_at.year - dob.year - ((as_at.month > dob.month || (as_at.month == dob.month && as_at.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

After that, as per @Baldrick:

```
validate :check_over_18

def check_over_18
  errors.add(:dob, "can't be under 18") if age < 18
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different questions here.

1. Where does the age calculation belong?

   The age calculation should either be a helper method or a model method.  I've always made it a model method but have recently seen the advantages of having these display elements in decorators or even helper methods.  In your case, start with putting it in the model then progress from there:

   ```
   def age
       now = Time.now.utc.to_date
       now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
   end
   ```
2. How do you validate that the person is over 18 years old?

   Are you really restricting someone from being saved to the database if they are under 18? Or are you limiting there viewing ability?

   ```
   def is_over_18?
       age >= 18
   end
   ```

And this write a custom each validator or use a Proc, but I really question the decision to validate in this way.

Comment: Not precise to the day. `((Date.new(2000).to_time - Date.new(1982).to_time) / 1.year ).floor # => 17`

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune I assume this has to do with leap years? Or something else?

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune updated my answer.  thanks for pointing this out.  I was thinking more on the "where" does the method belong then the method itself.  This should make it a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find age you can use the gem [adroit-age](https://github.com/raj-adroit/adroit-age)

```
age = AdroitAge.find_age("23/01/1990")
=> 23
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this too, but for months. Became way too complicated. The simplest way I could think of was:

```
def month_number(today = Date.today)
  n = 0
  while (dob >> n+1) <= today
    n += 1
  end
  n
end
```

You could do the same with 12 months:

```
def age(today = Date.today)
  n = 0
  while (dob >> n+12) <= today
    n += 1
  end
  n
end
```

This will use Date class to increment the month, which will deal with 28 days and leap year etc.