# In Rails, how do you program a method in a controller that will display a task that is supposed to be completed by today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Today should be considered today based on location. This is what I have in the `tasks_controller.rb` so far:

```
def day_task
  @tasks = Task.order(:due_date)
  @task_months = @tasks.where('due_date >= ? AND due_date <= ? AND user_id = ?', Time.current.beginning_of_day, Time.current.end_of_day, current_user.id)
end
```

Here's the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160322195458) do

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "due_date"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

My view displays the tasks with this code:

```
  <% @task_months.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to task.name, task %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>
    </tr>

  <% end %>
```

[Here's my repo.](https://github.com/hackmajor/Geeks2Code)

How do I do it?

Thank you.

-Chris

Comment: what is the problem with this code ??

Comment: In my time zone, it's displaying tasks for tomorrow, not today.

Comment: You need to know the users timezone and that's not stored anywhere.

Comment: Oh. So, I have to add a feature that asks for the timezone, then puts it into the method?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: did you set your locale like `Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'`?

Answer (score 0):

**How to get the timezone from user?**

You can ask user to set their timezone when they sign up with you. Then save the timezone as a user attribute in your database.

**The next question is how do you use the time zone?**

First, know that Time.current does not account for time zone. You should use Time.zone.now See ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7488362/388280

Therefore, do these

```
Time.zone = "Singapore" #Or set it according to the user's timezone 

Time.zone.now.to_date #then use it using Time.zone
```

To read more about Time zone -> http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. The problem for me was in `AND due_date <=`  What happens is that if the date stored is date/time then you are saying something like "is 2016-03-25 less than or equal to 2016-03-25 10:45"  It will not be true since the latter is later than the former.

I am using MS Sql Server. The cast as date statement worked for me.

My original question and my answer with more details is at [where using dates is not working properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221750/where-using-dates-is-not-working-properly)