# where using dates is not working properly.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to get a date search working properly for my two dates.

I am searching on the created_at date with the following in the searches model.

```
 # --------------------------  Begin created at dates ----------------------------
    # Only one date is filled in:
    documents = documents.where("documents.created_at >= ?", from_date) if from_date.present? and not to_date.present?
    documents = documents.where("documents.created_at <= ?", to_date - 1.day) if to_date.present? and not from_date.present?

    # Both Dates are filled in
    documents = documents.where("documents.created_at >= ?", from_date,)  if from_date.present? and to_date.present?
    documents = documents.where("documents.created_at <= ?", to_date) if to_date.present? and from_date.present?
```

Note that I tried a couple of variations of `to_date - 1.day` such as `to_date` and `to_date + 1.day`

I have a form with fields of from_date and to_date

If I enter just the from date e.g. 03/24/15, I get all of the items I would expect such as

```
    2016-03-24 
id  Subject Category    Author  Date Created    Date Updated     
32  Test Of Dates   Test    Christopher Mendla  03/24/16 16:45  03/24/16 16:45  Edit 
33  Friday  Test    Christopher Mendla  03/25/16 09:21  03/25/16 09:21
```

IOW, it works as expected.

However, if I set the to_date to 03/25/16, I get all of the records EXCEPT those records created on 3/25/16. If I search for a to_date of 03/26/16, then the records with a created_at of 3/25/16 are included.

I added the following to application.rb but note that this problem existed before setting the time zones (Yes, I know going with other than UTC for the data can cause problems but these are internal apps and other tools will be used to report from SQL. )

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: I am getting closer to a solution. It appears that searching for `created_at <= '2016-03-25'` will not show records created on 03/25/16. I did find some info about using ` cast ([created_at] as date) <= '2016-03-25' ` to look at only the date in the db and not the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to modify the SQL statement to change the stored date/time to a date. The Database is on MS Sql Server.

```
  # --------------------------  Begin created at dates ----------------------------
    # Only one date is filled in:
    documents = documents.where("documents.created_at >= ?", from_date) if from_date.present? and not to_date.present?
    documents = documents.where("cast (documents.created_at as date) <= ?", to_date) if to_date.present? and not from_date.present?

   # cast ([created_at] as date) <= '2016-03-25'

    # Both Dates are filled in
    documents = documents.where("documents.created_at >= ?", from_date,)  if from_date.present? and to_date.present?
    documents = documents.where("cast (documents.created_at as date) <= ?", to_date) if to_date.present? and from_date.present?
```

The `cast (documents.created_at as date)`  will compare the dates as dates and ignore the time. Apparently a stored date of 2016-03-25 11:40 is NOT less than or equal to 2016-03-25.

I did not use the cast as date on the from because I believe that 2016-03-25 11:40 IS >= 2016-03-25